# Update UINavigation Title as I Type in the UITextField

Tags: ios

I have a UITextField and I want that when I type in the UITextField it should update the NavigationBar title as I type.

I have the following code but this does not work well.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    self.navigationItem.title = textField.text;

    return YES;
}
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    self.navigationItem.title = newString;

    return YES;
}
```

Otherwise the string (textField.text) is the string before the new update is made.

Hope this helps :)

Let me know if anything is not clear!

NSRange is defined:

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
    NSUInteger location;
    NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

It doesn't do a lot, it's just quite convenient.

In terms of this method it just tells you which part of the textFields text will be replaced with the new string. When a user is typing on the end of the textField, the location will be the length of the text in the textField and the length will be 0. So no text will be replaced, it will just be inserted at the end... Make sense?

Comment: I can accept the answer in 11 minutes.. and I will. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain maybe little more about NSRange and what it does?

Comment: NSRange is just a simple struct with a location and a length. Just makes it a bit easier than passing two ints. Have added its definition above.